# SOAP webservices in android login not working

Tags: android, web-services, android-studio, soap, android-studio-2.3

I have an android application where I'm using SOAP webservices to login but I'm not getting logged in.
Here is code:

```
final EditText emailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailText);  
final EditText passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordText);  Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);
       loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                    request.addProperty("userName", emailText.getText().toString());
                    request.addProperty("userPassword", passwordText.getText().toString());

                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;

                    try {
                        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                        if (result != null){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
```

Here is error code I'm getting on pressing Login button:

```
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:165)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:76)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:152)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:69)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-06 16:17:10.379 12973-12973/com.example.moltoapps.webserviceapp W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: Why dont you try searching the exception...

Comment: tyczj can you please fix the code?

Comment: no read how to fix it yourself, all you have to do is click the link